# App Stops Working : Word Guess game stops working when clicking the list options

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I have made an app which takes words and definitions from two text files(one with word and other with definitions). A random number is used to generate a word to display and then shuffles and arranges 5 definitions along with the right one to display options. The app runs perfectly but when any option is clicked using listview, the app stops working.

```
ArrayList<String> word=new ArrayList<>();
List<String> dfn=new ArrayList<>();
String que="",ans="";
int counter=0;
private void random(){
    Random num = new Random();
    int nw = num.nextInt(word.size());

    que = word.get(nw);
    ans = dfn.get(nw);

    dfn.remove(ans);
    Collections.shuffle(dfn);
    dfn = dfn.subList(0,4);
    dfn.add(ans);
    Collections.shuffle(dfn);
}
TextView t;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.word2));
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.def2));
    while(sc.hasNextLine()&&sc2.hasNextLine()){
        String a = sc.nextLine();
        String b = sc2.nextLine();
        word.add(a);
        dfn.add(b);
```

i guess the above part is fine.

```
    }
    sc.close();
    sc2.close();
    random();
    t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t);
    t.setText(que);



    run();
}
ArrayAdapter<String> adap;
public void run(){
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.li);


    adap = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            dfn
    );

    list.setAdapter(adap);
    list.setOnItemClickListener((adapterView, view,i,l)->{//lambda expression
                if(dfn.get(i).equals(ans)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Correct!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    counter++;

                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wrong!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t2);
                t2.setText("Score : "+counter);
        random();
        t.setText(que);
        run();
            }

    );

}


}
```

Stack Trace :
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.ankitrath.wordguess, PID: 2769
                                                                               java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 264, Size: 5
                                                                                   at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.get(ArrayList.java:1049)
                                                                                   at com.example.ankitrath.wordguess.GameActivity.random(GameActivity.java:27)

```
 ans = dfn.get(nw);
```

Comment: post stacktrace

Comment: what is t2 ? Is it inside in listview ?

Comment: Just fixed the log cat and added the stack trace in the post

Comment: t2 is for displaying score

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am gonna try to describe clear problems in your code without the stacktrace. If i see cleary, the main problem could be the recursion code in your lambda expressions. This surely invokes `setOnItemClickListener` unnecessarily again and again. and also sets your adapter to the new one in each `run` call. Call `run` method only from `onCreate` method once and remove recursion call run from `setOnItemClickListener` and move recallable code into separated method. 
If you need sort items in ListView, then sort your data in your collection and then call

```
@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    //do your sorting here

    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

From what i see in stacktrace now, i can say that the main problem is in your `dfn` collection. Are you sure that these indicies are correct? Your code means that `word` and `dfn` collections have to be the same size but apparently they are not.

Comment: Okay, i am trying this one :) the stack trace is now available at the bottom

Comment: So the problem was with the shuffling, both had same indices but after shuffling this was not the case. the `ans` variable should be getting the random `dfn `before shuffling but it shuffled first and then assigned `ans`. So i created a copy of that list and used it for `ans`.